# Queues and Stacks Hiring and Firing

Tags: java, stack, queue

I finished this program and demo for my TA. I completely forgot one thing. So, the program is about hiring and firing people using stack and queues. I figured everything out except for one thing. I have to hire at least 3 people and whoever the first applicant is, I will hire them first so on. Here's the problem:

When I fire someone (The last person hired), that person should be the next person to get hired. Example:

```
Fired Name: b SS: 2

next person hired should be

Hired Name: b SS: 2.
```

I can't figure out how to get the last person fired to be the next person hired. Here's my program:

class Person {

```
public String name;
public String SS;

public Person(String N, String S) {
    this.name = N;
    this.SS = S;
}
}

class Manager {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private Queue<Person> app = new Queue<Person>();
public Stack<Person> hire = new Stack<Person>();
public Stack<Person> fire = new Stack<Person>();

public void Apply() throws QueueException {
    System.out.print("Applicant Name: ");
    String appName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("SSN: ");
    String appSS = keyboard.nextLine();
    Person apply = new Person(appName, appSS);
    app.enqueue(apply);

}

public void hire() throws QueueException {
    if (!app.isEmpty()) {
        Person newHire = hire.push(app.dequeue());
        System.out.println("Hired \nName: " + newHire.name + " SS: " + newHire.SS);
       //hire.push(app.dequeue());

    } else if (!fire.isEmpty()) {
        Person newFire = app.dequeue();
        System.out.println("Hired \nName: " + newFire.name + " SS: " + newFire.SS);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nobody to hire.");
    }
}

public void fire() throws StackException {
    if (!hire.isEmpty()) {
        Person newFire = fire.push(hire.pop());
        System.out.println("Fired \nName: " + newFire.name + " SS: " + newFire.SS);
        fire.push(hire.pop());

    } else {
        System.out.println("Nobody to fire");
    }

    }

}

public class Management {

public static void main(String[] args) throws QueueException, StackException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Manager user = new Manager();
    boolean test = true;

    while (test) {
        System.out.print("Press \n\t1 ACCEPT APPLICANT");
        System.out.print("\n\t2 Hire \n\t3 Fire \n\t4 Quit:");
        System.out.print("\nAnswer: \n");
        int action = keyboard.nextInt();
        String space = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (action == 1) {
            user.Apply();
        } else if (action == 2) {
            user.hire();
        } else if (action == 3) {
            user.fire();
        } else if (action == 4) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: maybe you can explain the scenarios a liitle bit more.

Comment: Basically, I'm a manager and hiring people. I'll press 1 to accept applicants. 2 to hire the first applicant. 3 to fire the last hired person. So, if I fire person B, person B should be the next person available for hiring.

Comment: This is a stack actually with last person fired going out top, so last in first out.

Comment: In your hiring code you're first checking the applicants for a person to hire.  If you you should be hiring the last fired person before a new applicant, swap your if/else if statements to look for someone in the fire stack first.

Answer (score 0):

you have this error on the hire() method.

```
Person newFire = app.dequeue();
```

you see that you are executing this line even tho app queue is Empty. just use fire stack instead of app queue.

```
public void hire() throws QueueException {
if (!app.isEmpty()) {
    Person newHire = hire.push(app.dequeue());
    System.out.println("Hired \nName: " + newHire.name + " SS: " + newHire.SS);
   //hire.push(app.dequeue());

} else if (!fire.isEmpty()) {
    Person newFire = fire.pop();
    hire.push(newFire);
    System.out.println("Hired \nName: " + newFire.name + " SS: " + newFire.SS);
} else {
    System.out.println("Nobody to hire.");
}
}
```